# What i need to do to replace PnP.Core.Services with CSOM for our Azure Function which uses .net 6.0

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, csom

I have an Azure Function which uses `PnP.Core.Services` to interact with SharePoint to create a list item. The Azure function is based on .net version 6.0.

I have this `startup.cs`:-

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp2.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
            var azureFunctionSettings = new AzureFunctionSettings();
            config.Bind(azureFunctionSettings);
            builder.Services.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.DisableTelemetry = true;
                var authProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(azureFunctionSettings.ClientId,
                    azureFunctionSettings.TenantId,
                    StoreName.My,
                    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                    azureFunctionSettings.CertificateThumbprint);
                options.DefaultAuthenticationProvider = authProvider;

                options.Sites.Add("Default", new PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration.PnPCoreSiteOptions

                {
                    SiteUrl = azureFunctionSettings.SiteUrl,
                    AuthenticationProvider = authProvider


                });

            });

        }

    }
}
```

and this `Function1.cs`:-

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1

    {
        private readonly IPnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory;
        public Function1(IPnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory)
        {
            this.pnpContextFactory = pnpContextFactory;

        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            using (var context = pnpContextFactory.Create("Default"))
            {
                var myList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SubFolders");
                Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Title", System.DateTime.Now }
    };

                // Use the AddBatch method to add the request to the current batch
                myList.Items.AddBatch(values);
                context.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this `AzureFunctionSettings.cs`:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    internal class AzureFunctionSettings
    {
        public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public StoreName CertificateStoreName { get; set; }
        public StoreLocation CertificateStoreLocation { get; set; }
        public string CertificateThumbprint { get; set; }


    }
}
```

now i am working with a client and they do not allow us to use any open source technologies like PnP. so what i need to do to replace my above PnP code with CSOM code? and is there a CSOM code for .net 6?

Thanks

Comment: What about using Graph API to communicate with SharePoint? Is there any reason why do you prefer CSOM?

Comment: @user2250152 i have been using CSOM for long time now

Comment: Where do you store the certificate? Have you ever run your code in production?

Comment: @user2250152 i am storing the certificate inside Azure Active Directory App

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client?view=msal-dotnet-latest) instead of PnP. I have never used the certificate flow myself but something like this should work:

```
  using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
  using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
  
  // ...
  // step 1: Acquire bearer token
  X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser,azureFunctionSettings.CertificateThumbprint);

  IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("your_client_id")
            .WithCertificate(certificate)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id/"))
            .Build();


  AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"https://yourSharePoint.sharepoint.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

  // step 2: Use bearer token with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext to access Sharepoint

  ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://yourSharePoint.sharepoint.com/");
        
  ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
  {
     e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + result.AccessToken;
  };

  //do your thing with ctx.Web.Lists etc.
```

The code to load your certificate from the store as in the [PnP source](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/blob/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UIExperience.Scanner/SharePoint.UIExperience.Scanner/Utilities/X509CertificateUtility.cs)

```
public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, string thumbprint)
    {
        // The following code gets the cert from the keystore
        X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection =
                store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                thumbprint, false);

        X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = certCollection.GetEnumerator();

        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            cert = enumerator.Current;
        }

        return cert;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but not sure if i understand the code , but seems this code will work for development purposes only as you are referring to local certificate `X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\your\certificate.pfx");`??

Comment: @johnGu I added the code to load the cert from the store.

Comment: from where i can define `StoreName.My` ? and what does it represent? thanks

Comment: @johnGu If there is a restriction not use open source then I'm not sure about Microsoft.Identity.Client: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet

Comment: @johnGu https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=net-6.0  It is in your original code too.

Comment: @user2250152 It is a Microsoft library...dotnet core is open source, too, so you'll have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: @StefanFFM I know. I'm confused why the client doesn't want to use PnP and what's the client's definition of open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSOM and authenticate with a certificate then you need to associate the certificate with your application in Azure. I assume that you have already generated the certificate and your application is registered in Azure Portal.

Open your app in Azure Portal and click on `Manage -> Certificates & secrets`.

[image]

On tab `Certificates` click on `Upload certificate` and upload certificate from `cer` file.

[image]

Now you need to create a new `Key vaults` resource in Azure portal

[image]

Remember your `Vault URI` of your `Key vault` resource [image]

Click on `Objects -> Certificates` and then on `Generate/Import` button to import the certificate from `pfx` file. Remember the name of the certificate.

[image]

In the code you need to add `Azure.Identity`, `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificate` and `Microsoft.Identity.Client` nuget packages.

Create `CertificateClient` to download the certificate from `Key vault` and use the certificate in `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`.

```
var certClient = new CertificateClient(new 
Uri("https://<your_vault_uri>.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

// download the certificate based on the name
var cert = certClient.DownloadCertificate("MyTestCertificate");

// use the certificate in ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

var confClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client_id>")
            .WithCertificate(cert)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/"))
            .Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await confClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"https://<tenant_name>.sharepoint.com/.default" })
               .ExecuteAsync();
var token = result.AccessToken;

// use the token to authenticate the request from CSOM 
var context = new ClientContext(new Uri("<your_web_url>");
    
context.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
{
   e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
};

// your code
...
```

Probably you will need to learn more about [DefaultAzureCredentail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) to configure it for using in production. `DefaultAzureCredential` tries different credential types.
For development you can choose an account for your apps to authenticate and access Azure resources in `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply will try this and let you know.. thanks

Comment: also when you mentioned `DownloadCertificat` where the certificate will be downloaded exactly ?

Comment: @johnGu The method is called DownloadCertificate but this method creates a new instance of X509Certificate2 class from the certificate stored in Key Vault. DownloadCertificate doesn't save the certificate on file system

Comment: @johnGu Do you need any further assistance?

Comment: @johnGu Try This Solution . I hope it will work for you. https://softans.com/question/what-i-need-to-do-to-replace-pnp-core-services-with-csom-for-our-azure-function-which-uses-net-6-0/#comment-491